# Getting variable result from the Main experiment to the Parameters Variation experiment - AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a parameter in the main experiment for which I'd like to run several variations to it and compare the results of a variable Patients holding the total patients number in each month across all the runs. I've created a dataset Pats in Main to store the variable result, and another dataset called datasetExp in a Parameters Variation experiment  where I'm trying to store the Main "Patients" var. result after each run, by placing the expression datasetExp.add(root.Pats); but I get the error message: "The method add(double) in the type DataSet is not applicable for the arguments (DataSet)"

Does anyone know why this happens? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a Dataset (`main.Pats`) to another Dataset in `ParameterVariation.datasetExp`. This does not make sense.

Check in the AnyLogic help what a Dataset is: a data structure that holds x/y value pairs. So you can only add double values, not entire datasets.

First, change your `main.Pats` to an int or double.

Next, add that at the end of a run to your `ParameterVariation.datasetExp`

Note: this assumes that you do not use replications for each ParamVariation.

However, you should, and there are various example models showing you how to do that.